# "Authentication service is not available" when installing IDLE (using python 2.7)

Tags: software-center, python, idle-python

I am getting this error installing IDLE on 12.10:

```
Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available.
(org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.95'}): 
org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

I can't install anything, even games. They all come up with the same error message.

Is there something I am missing? Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

A temporary workaround to this is:

```
sudo software-center
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

Also, it is possible your package manager is being blocked by another process, like an update in the background, or another install that did not complete. You can try rebooting, and then issuing the following, which will finish any incomplete installations:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: first solution worked for me! thanx

Comment: error returned... tried second solution also, but problem persists... it just dont ask me for my credentials, and that message appears...

Comment: not worked for me on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Had same problem, reconfiguring didn't fix it. Used `sudo dpkg --purge packageName` to clear out the offending entries.

Answer (score 2):

There were some updates pending for my ubuntu installation. I updated my ubuntu and everything started working fine for me afterwards.

thanks for all your help

With Regards
Gagan Janjua